# jquery clicking on list item is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-lists

I have this HTML and JS/jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#livesearch").on("click",  ".searchres", function(event){
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="livesearch">
  <?php foreach($data as $i){?>
    <li class="searchres"><?php echo $i["name"];?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This is part of a dropdown list that appears after an input form is being populated.

I would like to press on one of the dropdown lists `.searchres` and just print to console as a test.

This is, however, not printing on console. What am I doing wrong?

## Details

At the start of my php file I have this code snippet that creates a 'livesearch' object which connects to my database.

```
<?php
  require_once('livesearch.php');
  $livesearch = new livesearch();
  $data = null;
  
?>
```

I am declaring `$data=null` here because I do not want any database fields to show at loading time. could this be the issue that is making livesearch Id non-existant on load?

Comment: Your code works assuming you add the jQuery library and livesearch is a unique ID and the UL exists on the page when the event handler runs

Comment: Try `$(document).on("click",  "#livesearch .searchres", ...`

Comment: @mplungjan livesearch is a unique ID and jQuery is added and working....

Comment: @User863 that actually worked ! thank. Can you explain why that worked and my code did not?

Comment: If his suggestion worked then `<ul id="livesearch">` did not exist when the event handler is executed. If you insert the ul after document.ready, then you need to delegate from document and not from #livesearch

Comment: @mplungjan im calling jquery.js in head tag is that why livesearch is not found?

Comment: No. If <ul id="livesearch" does not exist at the time the page is loading (ajaxing the UL for example) then you need to delgate from document. If the UL is present at page load then your code SHOULD have worked

Comment: @mplungjan livesearch is declared in `<body>` tag i dont know why it should not exist. do elements in body tag exist on loading page?

Comment: Yes. There is something else going on. Your code is as in your question? I.e the click handler in load event

Comment: @mplungjan I updated the question with further details on code. Thanks

Comment: How does the code look when you click inspect on the livesearch object?